# Linux Mint 12: video runs at 2 to 3 times normal speed, for any browser

Tags: linux, drivers, video, linux-mint

I tried re-installing the nvidia graphics driver but no luck.  Videos run at an accelerated rate with No sound output for any browser (firefox and chrome) and with various sites like youtube and pandora.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there any difference between flashvideos and html5 videos? When using flash, try turning hardware acceleration off via right clicking on the video and changing the flash player settings.

Comment: I just tried disabling hardware settings from the flash menu, but the video is still quite accelerated when playing.

Comment: Was there any point in time where the speed was normal?

Comment: Yes.  The speed was normal up to the last few months.  I don't which package I may have installed that hosed up playback like that.  I also noticed that audio is also sped up with banshhee or vlc playing MP3 files.

Comment: Do you have other operating systems on your PC and if yes, do you experience the same problems with them. If you don't have another OS, try a livecd. And do you have the same problem with games?

Comment: Yes, my hp pavillion laptop has dual boot.  When I boot to Windows Vista, playback is just fine.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem but could at least help to provide more information for people who can. So what is about games? Are they faster too? (I have no clue but maybe it's some kind of timer issue).

Comment: I'm guessing it might be a video driver issue.  Thanks anyway.